# Shiny: updateSelectInput is blank after uploading data

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shiny-reactivity

I have a `Shiny` app that users upload a `.txt` file to and which users can then use to create a plot. The plot is conditional on the users selecting inputs based on the column names of their uploaded data. These inputs are drop down lists that have the column names in once the data is uploaded.

The app worked as of 23/01/2020. But today (25/01/2020), without any updates to the code, the drop down inputs no longer display the names of the uploaded data frames columns. There is no error given when running the app for the absence of the column names in the drop down list. Other than this issue the app runs perfectly (obviously no plot can be made though).

I have stripped out of the app the following code to give an example of uploading a data frame and using the drop down lists. The code is exactly as it appears in the app and works in this example. In order to get the same issue (missing column names in drop down lists) you need to clone the app from [GitHub](https://github.com/mattlee821/011_MR_Viz) as I haven't found a way to reproduce the missing column names.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

```r
# example data to upload to the app
data <- data.frame(this = 1:10, is = 1:10, some = 1:10, great = 1:10, example = 1:10, data = 1:10)
write.table(data, "data_frame.txt", 
            row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)


ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
    helpText("Select paramaters for data upload then upload data. Functions based on R read.table()."),

    checkboxInput(
      inputId = 'header',
      label = 'Header',
      value = TRUE
    ),

    checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),

    radioButtons(
      inputId = 'sep',
      label = 'Separator',
      choices = c(
        Comma = ',',
        Semicolon = ';',
        Tab = '\t',
        Space = ''
      ),
      selected = '\t'
    ),

    radioButtons(
      inputId = "quote",
      label = "Quote",
      choices = c(
        None = "",
        "Double Quote" = '"',
        "Single Quote" = "'"
      ),
      selected = '"'
    ),

    fileInput(
      inputId = "file1",
      label = "Track 1",
      multiple = TRUE,
      accept = c(
        "text/csv",
        "text/comma-separated-values",
        "text/plain",
        ".csv"
      )
    ),

    selectInput("label_column",
                "Label:",
                choices="", 
                selected = "")
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

# Read data from .csv/.txt files
track2_data1 <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
  rbindlist(
    lapply(
      input$file1$datapath,
      FUN = read.csv,
      header = input$header,
      sep = input$sep,
      quote = input$quote
    ),
    use.names = TRUE,
    fill = TRUE
  )
})

# drop down menu 
observeEvent(input$file1, {
  updateSelectInput(session,
                    "label_column",
                    choices = c("",colnames(track2_data1())))})
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`sessInfo()`:

Before running `shiny::runApp()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
  [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] compiler_3.6.2 tools_3.6.2    packrat_0.5.0
```

After running `shiny::runApp()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
  [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
  [1] markdown_1.1         rmarkdown_2.1        fs_1.3.1             stringr_1.4.0       
[5] shinycssloaders_0.3  dplyr_0.8.3          circlize_0.4.8       data.table_1.12.8   
[9] plotly_4.9.1         ggplot2_3.2.1        shinythemes_1.1.2    shinyLP_1.1.2       
[13] shinydashboard_0.7.1 shiny_1.4.0         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] shape_1.4.4         tidyselect_0.2.5    xfun_0.12           purrr_0.3.3         colorspace_1.4-1   
[6] vctrs_0.2.2         htmltools_0.4.0     viridisLite_0.3.0   yaml_2.2.0          rlang_0.4.3        
[11] later_1.0.0         pillar_1.4.3        glue_1.3.1          withr_2.1.2         lifecycle_0.1.0    
[16] munsell_0.5.0       gtable_0.3.0        htmlwidgets_1.5.1   GlobalOptions_0.1.1 evaluate_0.14      
[21] knitr_1.27          fastmap_1.0.1       crosstalk_1.0.0     httpuv_1.5.2        Rcpp_1.0.3         
[26] xtable_1.8-4        promises_1.1.0      scales_1.1.0        jsonlite_1.6        mime_0.8           
[31] packrat_0.5.0       digest_0.6.23       stringi_1.4.5       grid_3.6.2          tools_3.6.2        
[36] magrittr_1.5        lazyeval_0.2.2      tibble_2.1.3        crayon_1.3.4        tidyr_1.0.2        
[41] pkgconfig_2.0.3     rsconnect_0.8.16    assertthat_0.2.1    httr_1.4.1          rstudioapi_0.10    
[46] R6_2.4.1            compiler_3.6.2
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your `sessionInfo()`? I ran the code from your question and from the GH repo and it worked for me.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the session info before and after running the app

Comment: The only difference between our `sessionInfo()` are our OSs. The app from your question works perfectly; although, the one from your GH has some small bugs not only within the "label_colum" but also with some column names (i.e.: your data examples have a "Pvalue" column but when it's called from renderPlotly the app is calling the column "pvalue" which causes a small error). If it is easier for you, I can fork your repo and push some of those changes.

Comment: @Antarqui , just so I'm clear,  when you run the app from the GH the drop down lists populate with the column names from the uploaded data? And the only difference appears to be the OS? I have run the app on Windows 10 and two other Macs and the I have the same issue still. Don't worry about the other bugs these still need changes to work with all uploaded data frames - but thanks for the offer!!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this issue by removing `withSpinner()` from `ui.R`. This was located on line 261-263 :

```
mainPanel(
          withSpinner(uiOutput("pdf"))
        ))))),
```

The fix:

```
mainPanel((uiOutput("pdf")))
        )))),
```

I'm not quite sure why this fixed the issue though...

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the solution. I thought it was a problem related to repeated variables.